# Using same font style of an already defined algorithm function in another algorithm

Tags: fonts, algorithms

I want to use the same font style of a previously defined function in an algorithm environment when I call it in a different algorithm environment.

Below is a minimal working example. I want the same font style displayed for the  **IntPlus** function when I call it in the second function **MultPlus**.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm} 
\caption{Adding two integers $a$ by $b$.}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Require{$a, b$ are integers.} 
\Ensure{$c$ an integer.}
\Statex
\Function{IntPlus}{$a, b$}
\State {$c \gets a + b$}
\State \Return {$c$}
\EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm} 
\caption{Distributive property.}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Require{$a, b, c$ are integers.} 
\Ensure{$d$ an integer.}
\Statex
\Function{MultPlus}{$a, b, c$}
\State {$g \gets (a \times b) $}
\State {$d \gets \text{IntPlus}(g, c)$ } % I want the font style of IntPlus to be the same when first defined.
\State \Return {$c$}
\EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since `Function`s and `Procedure`s use the same syntax, you can use the procedure `\Call` command: replace `\text{IntPlus}(g, c)` with `\Call{IntPlus}{g, c}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\Call{<function name>}{<arguments>}`. `\Call` is designed for `\Procedure` calls, but `\Function`s share the same syntax. I'm sure @egreg will let me know if this usage is unwise. :-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm} 
\caption{Adding two integers $a$ by $b$.}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Require{$a, b$ are integers.} 
\Ensure{$c$ an integer.}
\Statex
\Function{IntPlus}{$a, b$}
\State {$c \gets a + b$}
\State \Return {$c$}
\EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm} 
\caption{Distritive property.}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Require{$a, b, c$ are integers.} 
\Ensure{$d$ an integer.}
\Statex
\Function{MultPlus}{$a, b, c$}
\State {$g \gets (a \times b) $}
\State {$d \gets \Call{IntPlus}{g, c}$ } 
\State \Return {$c$}
\EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]